# HTML Tag in Array Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom, vue.js

**The Requirement** is to append an HTML element from Array Value to DOM

```
template: {
    0: {
       h1: '<h1>Hi</h1>'
    },
    1: {
       h2: '<h2>Hi</h2>'
    },
    2: {
       h3: '<h3>Hi</h3>'
    }
}
```

I have a **VueJS For Loop**:

```
        <div v-for="temp in template">
            {{ temp.h1}}
        </div>
```

**DOM :**

```
<h1>hi</h1>
```

Comment: You need to elaborate more on your problem. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to append array value to DOM, with HTML querys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use **v-html** binding to inject raw html in page.

Something like this:

```
<div v-for="temp in template">
    <div v-html="temp.h1">
</div>
```

Check here for more info: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML